# Modificar Valor De Un Bean y Recogerlo En Otra Clase Distinta

Tags: java, spring-boot

Buenas a todos

(Resumen al final)
Estoy intentando pasar una lista de mapas de una clase a otra usando un bean con configuración XML:

```
<bean id="listParamJob"
      class="java.util.ArrayList">
</bean>
```

Aqui es donde le pongo el valor:

```
    private void crearBoton() {

        NativeButton botonSimple = new NativeButton("Guardar Consulta");
        botonSimple.setIcon(FontAwesome.CLOUD_UPLOAD);

        botonSimple.addClickListener((Button.ClickEvent e) -> {

            String consulta = areaConsultas.getValue();

            paramsLista = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) context.getBean("listParamJob");
            paramsLista = extraerSelect(consulta);

            crearNotificacion("Éxito", "Consulta Guardada", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
        });

        this.addComponent(botonSimple);
    }
```

areaConsultas es un TextArea a continuación os pongo el método de extraerSelect:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> extraerSelect(String consultaEntera) {
        String[] consultasArray = consultaEntera.split("\n");

        String consultasSpliteadas = Arrays.toString(consultasArray);

        System.out.println(consultasSpliteadas);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaMapas = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> mapaConsulta;

        int contadorConsulta = 0;
        for (String cadenaSacada : consultasArray) {
            mapaConsulta = new HashMap<>();

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(cadenaSacada);

            int contador = 0;
            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                String tokenSacado = st.nextElement().toString();
                if (contador == 1) {
                    mapaConsulta.put("sql.consulta", consultasArray[contadorConsulta]);
                    mapaConsulta.put("sql.select", tokenSacado);
                    System.out.println(tokenSacado);
                    break;
                }
                contador++;
            }
            contadorConsulta++;
            listaMapas.add(mapaConsulta);
        }
        return listaMapas;
    }
```

y cuando desde otra clase intento llamar a esta lista me da que no tiene nada.

Ya comprobé con el debug que en las clases anteriores se me añade el Hashmap a la lista por tanto no esta vacía os pongo donde consigo el valor de la lista (Que dice que está vacía):

```
public void crearJob() {

    context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
    listaMapasParams = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) context.getBean("listParamJob");

    boolean exito = true;

    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("consultaResultJob");

    JobParameters parametros = null;
    JobExecution execution = null;

    annadirCadenas("Creando Job: " + job.getName());
    int contadorMapas = 0;

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    // Aqui es donde leo listaMapasParams, pero como es de longitud 0 no hace nada 
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    for (HashMap<String, String> mapaSacado : listaMapasParams) {

        try {
            parametros = crearParametrosJob(mapaSacado, contadorMapas);
        } catch (ConsultaNoDefinidaException ex) {
            String ERROR = "Error: No Hay Una Consulta Definida";
            LOG.warning(ERROR);
            annadirCadenas(ERROR);
            exito = false;
        }

        annadirCadenas("Pasando Parámetros Al Job");

        if (parametros == null) {
            annadirCadenas("No Se pudo Ejecutar El Job Debido A Que No Hay Definida Ninguna Consulta");
        } else {

            try {
                annadirCadenas("Ejecutando Job Con Los Siguientes Parámetros: \n" + parametros.toString());
                execution = ((JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher")).run(job, parametros);
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Job Estado De Finalizaci\u00f3n : {0}", execution.getStatus());
                annadirCadenas("Job Finalizado, Estado: " + execution.getStatus());
            } catch (JobExecutionException jee) {
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Job: " + job.getName() + " Fall\u00f3 , Raz\u00f3n:{0}", jee.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if ((exito) && (execution != null)) {
            crearNotificacion("Éxito", "Job Ejecutado Con Éxito", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            crearNotificacion("Fallo", "Falló La Ejecución Del Job", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        System.out.println("Contador:" + contador);
        contador = contador + 1;
        System.out.println("Contador Despues:" + contador);

        contadorMapas++;
    }
    contador = 0;
}
```

He puesto en las dos clases:

```
@Component
@Scope("step")
```

A continucación os explico lo que hace el programa:

uso vaadin para la interfaz gráfica, Spring boot y Spring batch la configuración la hice por XML, porque no tenía claro como se hacían los job por anotaciones

Lo que hace este programa es a traves de un textArea recoger consultas separadas por saltos de línea que posteriormente las spliteo para recoger los valores de la select

Entonces le paso al job la consulta entera mas los campos de la select

Mas adelante meto los campos de la select recogidos y los spliteo de nuevo para meterlos a un mapa que recoja nombre de campo a recuperar y el valor recuperado de la base de datos y asi poder usarlo en el rowmapper para despues meterlo a un CSV el resultado de la consulta

Para resumir:

Pones consultas en un textArea separadas por saltos de linea despues un reader lee de la base de datos y un writter lo escribe en un csv los resultados de la consulta

Para resumir el problema:

¿Como puedo modificar un bean para que otra clase pueda leerlo y no esté vacío ?

Donde está dando vacío es en el método crear Job(Hay puesto 1 comentario para que se visualice mejor):

```
for (HashMap<String, String> mapaSacado : listaMapasParams) {
```

Muchas Gracias por Adelantado a Todos Por Leerme